# How have you implemented a Cover Flow ui in the web browser?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, apache-flex

Something that is similar to the Cover Flow in iTunes.

I can use Adobe Flash, Flex, or pure html/javascript.

HOWEVER, I need a pointed to production ready code.  I've looked at plenty of examples in both Flex and HTML that aren't ready for prime time.  No demo code needed.

Here's my requirements for production ready:
1) Memory leaks are under control.
2) Works like a river with larger data sets, paging in sub-sets in some set number.  The component/code needs to be able to handle 100+ items to flow through, preferable up to 500.

Any suggestions?  I'm OK if the answer is "haven't seen this used effectively" or "probably not advisable for large data sets".

Comment: Perhaps you could edit these examples so they *are* ready for "prime time".

Comment: I would, but the budget doesn't allow for that kind of time.  Especially the Adobe Flex one's I looked at.  And, I'm not really sure if such a thing should be pulled off in javascript yet...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it, but have you tested the performance of Doug McCune's?

http://dougmccune.com/blog/2007/11/19/flex-coverflow-performance-improvement-flex-carousel-component-and-vertical-coverflow/

I'm pretty sure it doesn't page, but paging is usually better handled with a dataProvider

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at any of the components in flash den?

http://flashden.net/searches?term=coverflow&type=files

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this done with HTML5 and Javascript:

http://blarnee.com/wp/open-source-javascript-coverflow/

Unfortunately that won't work in IE.

There's also a Silverlight implementation:

http://silverlightcoverflow.codeplex.com/

As well as the Flex one already suggested by Sean.